# How can I play old Final Cut Pro .mov files? (VLC only plays the audio.)

Tags: macos, video, vlc-media-player, quicktime, final-cut-pro

A few years ago, I exported some .mov files from Final Cut Pro on my old Mac Pro. I am positive that I made them self-contained files, so they didn't need to reference the original footage. I backed them up on Time Machine.

Now I have an MacBook Air with Yosemite 10.10.2. Time Machine is no longer supported, but I've managed to find those files on the hard drive I used to back them up on Time Machine. But I can't open them.

QuickTime 10.2 tells me it can't open the files. I tried QuickTime Player 7 and it begins "Searching for movie data in file..." (the original reference file). I tried VLC and it's able to play the audio track, but not the video. (This confirms that they are self-contained files, right?) I don't have FCP on this computer.

Other .mov files play just fine. Any thoughts on what's wrong and how I can get them to play?

Comment: What do you mean by "Time Machine is no longer supported"? I use Time Machine on Yosemite 10.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MediaInfo Mac](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Mac_OS) - the latest version is a whole 99 cents in the App Store, but the previous version is still freeware & works on Yosemite.

At minimum, it will confirm whether there is actually a video stream in the .mov container; if so, it will give further details which may explain why it's not working.

Example output…

[image]